# Querying Elasticsearch with escaped quotes in python requests

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-requests

I'm trying to query `elasticsearch` using python `requests`. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930235/querying-elasticsearch-with-python-requests-not-working-fine), I'm using the following process:

```
params = {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": r'\"text in quotes\"'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "from": 1458581389860,
                                    "to": 1458494989000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 100,
}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Unfortunately, the quotation marks in the query don't appear to be properly escaped for elasticsearch. I've also tried:

- `'\\"text in quotes\\"'`
- `response = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(params))`

The equivalent curl, which works, looks as follows:

```
curl -XGET 'MYURL/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "\"test in quotes\""
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "from": 1458581389860,
                                    "to": 1458494989000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 100,
}'
```

Comment: `'\\"text in quotes\\"'` is the same as `r'\"text in quotes\"'`

Comment: That's what I thought. Could `requests` be doing something to the string after the value is passed?

Comment: It might, but I don't know why it would. Have you tried to use the python elasticsearch library?

Comment: Also, did you read the answer on the link you provided? The `params` parameter is not for data being sent. If you're trying to send data to the server you should specifically be using the `data` parameter

Comment: I'm trying to send query parameters as outlined in the link, which is why I used the `params` parameter. I have also tried sending the query via a json dump of the above dict using the `data` parameter, but to no avail.

Comment: I think the problem is the cURL is using `\"` to escape the quotes. In Python you only need to do `r'"text in quotes"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that uri being used in the python example went to `http` whereas the uri for the `curl` example was `https`. It works with the following changes:

- http -> https
- the string as `'"text in quotes"'`
- sent the query as data `response = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(params))`

I don't understand why it was partially working before, 100 hits were being returned.

Answer (score 1):

In cURL, you are escaping the quotes. `"\"text in quotes\""`, and this will become `"text in quotes"`.

Your Python problem is that you don't need to escape anything if you use single quotes like you've done with `r'\"text in quotes\"'` that will print `\"text in quotes\"` because it is a raw string containing the slashes.

So, you have two options:

1. Use double quotes for the Python string and escape `"\"text in quotes\""`
2. Just use single quotes with un-escaped double quotes `'"text in quotes"'`

Comment: That's the first approach that I tried. Maybe the string isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is not the problem, be careful of character encoding. Try to manage it and use UTF-8.